# failure of the underlying provider of open on connecting to .mdf file

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, mdf

i'm tring to publish my desktop application (Winform application) that i used SQL SERVER 2008 on development.
So befor set a setup project to my application i create an "App_Data" folder on my application and copy the .mdf file on it

then i modifier the connectionstring on "App.Config" file like this

```
<add name="ApplicationPCLMEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.PCLM.csdl|res://*/Model.PCLM.ssdl|res://*/Model.PCLM.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ApplicationPCLM.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

I'um using EntityFramework

so when i run the application i get this error

```
failure of the underlying provider of open
```

Comment: (LocalDb) is installed on the "target" Computer ?

Comment: no i have MSSQLSERVER installed

Comment: In your connection string I read:
Data Source=(LocalDb)

Comment: What is the edition of installed SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using local db then there is no need for creating appdata folder because it is already present in there instead try

```
  <add name="ApplicationPCLMEntities" connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=ApplicationPCLM ;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: the problem i want to create an .exe file and attach the mdf file to it